# Error Installing OCI8 on Ubuntu 23.10 PHP 8.2

Tags: ubuntu, php, pecl

I'm running Apache 2.4 on a Ubuntu 23.10 server with PHP 8.2 and I can't install the OCI8 extension in order to connect to Oracle.

I previously had a PHP 5.6 built from a makefile which I recently removed manually, since there was no package to uninstall.

I installed the Oracle instant client 12.2 and `php-pear`. I checked I am able to connect to the database through sqlplus. When I run: `pecl install oci8` I get this error:

> checking for Oracle Database OCI8 support... yes, shared checking PHP version... configure: error: You need at least PHP 8.1.0 to be able to use this version of OCI8. Use OCI8 2.0 for PHP 5.6.31

It seems pecl still believes I'm running PHP 5.6. I created symbolic links from the PHP 8.2 to the old PHP, otherwise pecl wouldn't start as it's still looking for a php binary in /usr/bin/php:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/php8.2 /usr/bin/php
```

`phpinfo` and `php -v` both show PHP 8.2 as the version that's running.

I tried to reinstall PHP 8.2 and `php-pear`, but it says I already have the newest version.

What can I do to solve this error and be able to install OCI8?

---

**Edit**: Running `which php` gives `/usr/local/bin/php` and `which pecl` yields `/usr/local/bin/pecl`.

I ran `pecl channel-update pecl.php.net` before installing OCI8 and I got the message `Channel "pecl.php.net" is up to date`.

Comment: Try doing `pecl channel-update pecl.php.net` and then running `pecl install oci8`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to install OCI8 after changing some of the pear settings:

```
pear config-set php_bin /usr/bin/php8.2
pear config-set php_ini /etc/php/8.2/apache2/php.ini
pear config-set php_suffix 8.2
```

Comment: Great self-solved answer!